Big O and monotone functions part II
This is a continuation of my previous question on big O and monotone functions.
The problem I want to solve is the following.
Given monotonically increasing functions $f$ and $g$, under what assumptions can we conclude from $f(x) = O(g(x))$ that the limit
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$
exists.
My conjecture is that if $f$ doesn't vary much slower than $g$ grows (this needs to be made precise), then the statement is true.
Let me explain where this conjecture comes from.
Under the extra assumptions that $f$ and $g$ are also positive and differentiable, denote by
$\displaystyle h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.
That $f(x) = O(g(x))$ is equivalent to $\displaystyle \limsup_{x \to \infty} h(x) = M < \infty$.
Now, assume by contradiction that $\displaystyle \liminf_{x \to \infty} h(x) = m < M$, and choose $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $M - m - 2\varepsilon > 0$.
Next, look at the derivative of $f$:
$\displaystyle f'(x) = g'(x)h(x) + g(x)h'(x)$.
For any $x_0$ there exists $x_2 > x_1 \geq x_0$ such that $h(x_1) > M - \varepsilon$ and $h(x_2) < m + \varepsilon$.
By the mean value theorem there then exists $x^* \in (x_1, x_2)$ such that
$\displaystyle h'(x^*) = \frac{h(x_2) - h(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} < \frac{m - M + 2\varepsilon}{x_2 - x_1} < 0$.
This gives the following estimate
$\displaystyle f'(x^*) < g'(x^*)(M + \varepsilon) - g(x^*)\frac{M - m - 2\varepsilon}{x_2 - x_1}$,
where each of the terms $g'(x^*)$, $(M + \varepsilon)$, $g(x^*)$ and $(M - m - 2\varepsilon)/(x_2 - x_1)$ are positive.
Assuming we choose $x_1$ and $x_2$ as close to each other as possible for each $x_0$. Then we can make $f'(x^*) < 0$ if $g(x^*)$ grows faster than $g'(x^*)(x_2 - x_1)$.
This would then be a contradiction to $f$ being monotone.
Can this heuristic be made into a precise statement about the variation of $f$ compared to the growth of $g$, that also don't assume $f$ and $g$ are differentiable?

If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, $|g|\to +\infty$,  and eventually $g'\neq 0$, then L'Hopital's Rule gives you a basic sufficient condition.
